# Bootstrap 4.0.0 sidebar: how to avoid vertical extension when opening?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sidebar, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Sidebar using bootstrap 4.0.0, to get a vertical menu for my website.

Here is the actual code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('fliph');
  });
});
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
ol {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/***********************  TOP Bar ********************/

.sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.bg-defoult {
  background-color: #222;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sidebar li a,
.sidebar li a.collapsed.active {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 0px solid #dedede;
  text-decoration: none
}

.sidebar li a.active {
  background-color: #000;
  border-left: 5px solid #dedede;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

.sidebar li a i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.sidebar ul li .sub-menu li a {
  position: relative
}

.sidebar ul li .sub-menu li a:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sidebar ul li .sub-menu li a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #111;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar ul li .sub-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #222;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
}

.sub-menu {
  border-left: 5px solid #dedede;
}

.sidebar li a .nav-label,
.sidebar li a .nav-label+span {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
}

.sidebar.fliph li a .nav-label,
.sidebar.fliph li a .nav-label+span {
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
}

.sidebar.fliph {
  width: 42px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar.fliph li {
  position: relative
}

.sidebar.fliph .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 39px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button> <i class="fa fa fa-th-large" >-india-7615949353 </i></button>

<div class="sidebar left ">
  <ul class="list-sidebar bg-defoult">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dashboard" class="collapsed active"> <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label"> Dashboards </span> <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span> </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="dashboard">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> <span class="nav-label">Layouts</span></a> </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> <span class="nav-label">Graphs</span> <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span> </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span class="nav-label">Grid options</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tables" class="collapsed active"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span class="nav-label">Tables</span><span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="tables">
        <li><a href=""> Static Tables</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Data Tables</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Foo Tables</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> jqGrid</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#e-commerce" class="collapsed active"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="nav-label">E-commerce</span><span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="e-commerce">
        <li><a href=""> Products grid</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Products list</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Product edit</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Product detail</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cart</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Credit Card form</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href=""><i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i> <span class="nav-label">Metrics</span> </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> <span class="nav-label">Other Pages</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> <span class="nav-label">Other Pages</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> <span class="nav-label">Other Pages</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> <span class="nav-label">Other Pages</span></a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> <span class="nav-label">Other Pages</span></a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It works almost fine, the only problem I am facing is about the sidebar extending vertically when I click on the toggle button on top of the sidebar. As I could understand, it's related to the space needed for displaying the title on each list-item. Would it be possible to limit this behavior by keeping each list item on just one "line"?

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual question is? Do you mean you don't like how the animation works when it's toggled?

Comment: Sure, what I'm asking for, is, how to avoid the sidebar growing in height when the animation is triggered. Maybe it would be more evident by running the  code snippet at full screen.